# Using a variable outside of a loop, value changes within the loop

Tags: c, loops, variables

I am relatively new to programming and I have come across an issue whilst trying to write a function that utilizes loops. The function should work as such:

The array Data consists of a 51X2 set of doubles, which are all used in the program through the initial for loop, the a variable and the b variable. The X and Y variables are both set to the minimum values of the array.

Using the a and X variables as an example, the X value is compared to a and incremented until it surpasses a. The number of loop iterations are tracked by the c variable. This c variable is then used in the Graph array. The same procedure occurs for the b and Y variables. This process is repeated for every value of S to analyse all data points from the Data array.

The issue I'm having is that the `c` and `d` variables don't change relative to the changes inside the loops. The variables will not change from their initialized value. I am looking to find a solution that allows for the `c` and `d` variables to change in relation to the number of iterations of the for loop.

The relevant function code can be seen below:

```
void Data_Plot(double Data[51][2], char Graph[44][56])
{
    int N = 50;
    int S,q,r;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    double a = Data[S][0];
    double b = Data[S][1];
    double X = Data[0][0];
    double Y = Data[0][1];
    for (S=0;S<N;S++)
    {   
        for(X;X<a;X+=0.1428571429)
        {
            c++;
        }
        for(Y;Y<b;Y+=2)
        {
            d++;
        }

        Graph[c][d] = '*'; 
    }
```

I am aware that my code is very unoptimized and messy, but I can fix those issues up with future projects after I have finished this one.

Edit: I would like to note that I have attempted this with `c` and `d` being set to other values, as well as being left as NULL. The same result occurred regardless of the variable initialization.

Comment: You did not initialize `S` when accessing it in `double a = Data[S][0];`

Comment: `S` is not initialized when you initialize `a` and `b` so you have undefined behaviour — anything can happen and it is OK.  Also, on the `S == 1` iteration of the outer loop (and all subsequent iterations), `X` is already too big; you never reset it back to `data[0][0]`.

Comment: I have initialised S now, thank you for the heads up, however the code still functions in the same manner.

Comment: do you even know that your loops are being executed?

Comment: Thank you very much Barmar! I moved the a and b variables within the loop and now the code functions perfectly! Could someone explain to me why this made such a big difference?

Comment: `S` is still uninitialised when you use it for initialising `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `a` and `b` depend on `S`, which you change during the `for` loop, you need to move those variables inside the loop.

```
void Data_Plot(double Data[51][2], char Graph[44][56])
{
    int N = 50;
    int S,q,r;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    double X = Data[0][0];
    double Y = Data[0][1];
    for (S=0;S<N;S++)
    {   
        double a = Data[S][0];
        for(X;X<a;X+=0.1428571429)
        {
            c++;
        }

        double b = Data[S][1];
        for(Y;Y<b;Y+=2)
        {
            d++;
        }

        Graph[c][d] = '*'; 
    }
```

Comment: This was exactly the answer I needed, thank you very much! It did not occur to me that I would need the variables within the loop if they depended on S. Very much appreciated.

Comment: It's odd that `X` and `Y` don't need resetting per iteration.  At the least, the `for (X; …)` and `for (Y; …)` notation in the question is peculiar.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point. And probably `c` and `d` need to be set back to `0` each time as well. I don't really understand what he's graphing.

Comment: The purpose was to graph a pre-defined set of values from a text file, which represent the cubic function. I have since tested the code and it outputs the correct graphical function. I will bear all of this advice in mind for any future projects however.